# 12pt font size with APS PRL style option and REVTEX document class

Tags: fonts, fontsize, revtex, journal

[image]I'm preparing a document for submission to APS PRL and irrespective of what font size I specify in the header, the output always appears in 12pt. As you can see specifying twocolumn should give already 10pt font size by default, but it does not work.
I am using texmaker to work on latex.

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,twocolumn,superscriptaddress,showpacs]{revtex4}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

I have included a screenshot of the log file.

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) I don't really get the problem. With this code I get the default 10pt size, if I add `12pt` as class option I get 12pt font.

Comment: It should be like that, but I am not getting the 10pt font with the code. I have no idea what the problem is. I compared with another paper where I get 10pt, and the result is different.

Comment: Do you get warnings? Which fonts does the PDF use? How are you compiling? Post your log file somewhere.

Comment: I have included a screenshot of the log file.

Comment: `revtex4-1` is the latest version of the class and the one PRL will expect you to be submitting with.  Do you experience problems using that instead of `revtex4`?

Comment: It seems it works when using revtex4-1. Thanks!